# REACT NATIVE - Can't install Realm Sync - Expo version 44

Tags: node.js, react-native, expo, realm

I want to create a mobile app with React Native. I am using Expo and I want to use Realm Sync as my DB.

Info:

- Im working on vs code (on mac)
- Node.js version: 16.18.0
- React version: 18.2.0
- React native version: 0.69.6
- npm 8.19.0

Problem:
We have installed Expo version 44 (because a later or earlier version of Expo does not match with realm), but can still not install Realm Sync. When I run
"npm install realm", I get the error below:

```
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! While resolving: realm@11.0.0
npm ERR! Found: react-native@0.69.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peer react-native@"*" from @react-native-community/cli@8.0.6
npm ERR!   node_modules/@react-native-community/cli
npm ERR!     @react-native-community/cli@"^8.0.4" from react-native@0.69.6
npm ERR!   react-native@"0.69.6" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peerOptional react-native@">=0.70.0" from realm@11.0.0
npm ERR! node_modules/realm
npm ERR!   realm@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react-native@0.70.4
npm ERR! node_modules/react-native
npm ERR!   peerOptional react-native@">=0.70.0" from realm@11.0.0
npm ERR!   node_modules/realm
npm ERR!     realm@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

We have followed severol tutorials. One of them are [Quick start with Sync](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start/)

We are obviously missing something.
Can someone please help?

Comment: I would guess a step was missed setting up the environment - at least that's what the error(s) appear to indicate. For example did you do this `npm install -g expo-cli` to install the expo cli? If so, were there any errors? I would take a step back and set up a standard app first, following the [Realm Expo Guide](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/react-native/quick-start-expo/). And see how that goes.

Answer (score 0):

Try it: npm install realm@10.6.0

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).